# Determine R Data Frame Row Values from Column Value Comparison

Tags: r, dataframe

I’m trying to compare the values in column C and return the rows that are associated with them . An example would be to compare the first two values in column C. If the first value is greater than the second, return the first two rows in a data frame. If the first value is not greater then skip  to the next set, and compare and see if the third value from column C is greater than the fourth. If this is the case return rows 3 and 4. if not skip to the next set.

I’ve been wrangling with the `filter` function from `dplyr` but no luck.

Below is a example data frame.

```
set.seed(99)
DF <- data.frame(abs(rnorm(10)), abs(rnorm(10)), abs(rnorm(10)))
colnames(DF) <-c("A", "B", "C")
DF
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rollapply` from `zoo` package,

```
library(zoo)
ind <- rep(rollapply(DF$C, 2, by = 2, which.max) == 1, each = 2)
DF[ind,]
            A         B          C
#1  1.52984334 2.0127251 1.70922539
#2  1.96454540 0.2887642 0.52301701
#5  1.15765833 0.2866493 1.72702076
#6  0.80379719 1.0945894 0.72269558
#7  1.52239099 0.5296913 2.04080511
#8  0.01663749 0.3593682 0.88601771
#9  0.12672258 0.4110257 0.19165526
#10 0.27740770 0.1950477 0.01378397
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base `R` solution you can try with where you find the index for every two rows based on the condition and then do a subset on the data frame:

```
ind <- which(DF$C[c(T, F)] > DF$C[c(F, T)])  # check whether the odd rows are larger than
# the even rows and find out the index
DF[c(2*ind-1, 2*ind), ]   # subset the data frame based on index for every two rows
#            A         B         C
# 1  1.6866933 0.6886403 1.1231086
# 9  0.8781335 2.1689560 1.3686023
# 2  0.8377870 0.5539177 0.4028848
# 10 0.8215811 1.2079620 0.2257710
```

Comment: The rollapply() function seems to work best for my application. The reason being is I need to extending this to larger running windows and define different criteria to return specified rows. I can define my own functions and replace the which.max to define what it returns.